# How to make an icon on android through a webapp?

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications

I found out that

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />
```

is a way to make an icon on iPhones.

What is the way to make an icon on androids?

Also are there other ways to implement creating an icon which is linked to simply a mobile website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually can't. This functionality is unique to iOS devices.

EDIT:
However, some browsers may use the standard favicon used by most browsers.